# Navbar is overflowing when added the postion fixed to it

Tags: html, css, nav

I am working on a project with html, css and javascript. But I have a problem with the navbar as it is overflowing the content in the screens bigger than 2050px. I have tried to solve it but it seems like hard. If someone knows the answer please let me know. It is happening when I add position fixed to my navbar.

[Here is the screenshot of my overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3Lx4.jpg)

Styles for my project can be found by [styles.css](https://dev.ontvangbitcoin.nl/styles.css)

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Goedkoper dan pin en veiliger dan cash. Verbreed jouw   klantenkring met Bitcoin. Bekijk de demo">
    <title>Bitcoin voor winkeliers, horeca en ondernemers - Ontdek de voordelen</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon"  href="images/bitcoin-logo.svg">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div data-include-html="header.html"></div> 
        <div class="background-image">
            <img src="images/voorbeeld-bitcoin-lightning-betaling-480.webp" 
                srcset="images/voorbeeld-bitcoin-lightning-betaling-320.webp 320w,
                        images/voorbeeld-bitcoin-lightning-betaling-480.webp 480w,
                        images/voorbeeld-bitcoin-lightning-betaling-600.webp 600w,
                        images/voorbeeld-bitcoin-lightning-betaling-768.webp 768w,
                        images/voorbeeld-bitcoin-lightning-betaling-1024.webp 1024w,
                        images/voorbeeld-bitcoin-lightning-betaling-1280.webp 1280w,
                        images/voorbeeld-bitcoin-lightning-betaling-1600.webp 1600w"
                sizes="(max-width: 320px) 320px,
                        (max-width: 480px) 480px,
                        (max-width: 600px) 600px,
                        (max-width: 768px) 768px,
                        (max-width: 1024px) 1024px,
                        (max-width: 1280px) 1280px,
                        1600px"
                alt="Voorbeeld van een Bitcoin Lightning betaling in een winkel">
        </div>

        <div class="paragraph">
            <div>
                <h1>Voordelen van Bitcoin ontvangen</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <button class="button"><span>Demo</span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>

        <div data-include-html="footer.html"></div>
   
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </div>  
    </body>
    </html>
```

Header.html

```
<nav>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <span onclick=hideSidebar() class="close"><a href="#"><svg 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" width="24"><path d="m256-200-56-56 224-224-224-224 56-56 224 224 224-224 56 56-224 224 224 224-56 56-224-224-224 224Z"/></svg></a></span>
    <div class="rest-menu">
        <span><a href="index.html" aria-label="Home">Home</a></span>
        <span><a href="#" aria-label="Demo">Demo</a></span>
        <span><a href="vraag-en-antwoord.html" aria-label="Vraag & antwoord">Vraag & antwoord</a></span>
        <span><a href="#" aria-label="Praktijk cases">Praktijk cases</a></span>
        <span><a href="#" aria-label="Starten">Starten</a></span>
        <span><a href="#" aria-label="Contact">Contact</a></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flex">
    <div>
        <a href="index.html" aria-label="Logo" class="logo">
            <img src="images/bitcoin-logo.svg" alt="Navigation Bar" height="50" width="50" srcset="images/bitcoin-logo.svg 50w, images/bitcoin-logo.svg 100w" sizes="(max-width: 600px) 50px, 100px">
            <span class="logotext">bitcoin</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="desk">
        <span><a href="index.html" class="hideOnMobile" aria-label="Home">Home</a></span>
        <span><a href="#" class="hideOnMobile" aria-label="Demo">Demo</a></span>
        <span><a href="vraag-en-antwoord.html" class="hideOnMobile" aria-label="Vraag & Antwoord">Vraag & antwoord</a></span>
        <span><a href="#" class="hideOnMobile" aria-label="Praktijk cases">Praktijk cases</a></span>
        <span><a href="#" class="hideOnMobile" aria-label="Starten">Starten</a></span>
        <span><a href="#" class="hideOnMobile" aria-label="Contact">Contact</a></span>
        <span class="menu-button">&#9776;</span>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Footer.html

```
<footer>
    <div class="top">

    <ul class="text">
        <li><a href="index.html" aria-label="Footer Home" 
class="Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" aria-label="Footer Demo">Demo</a></li>
        <li><a href="vraag-en-antwoord.html" aria-label="Vraag & 
antwoord">Vraag & antwoord</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" aria-label="Footer Praktijk Cases">Praktijk 
cases</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" aria-label="Footer Starten">Starten</a> 
</li>
        <li><a href="#" aria-label="Footer Contact">Contact</a> 
</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-bottom">
        <p>© 2024 CC0 / Public Domain. ontvangbitcoin.nl is met ❤️ 
gemaakt door enthousiaste Bitcoin community bijdragers. <a 
href="https://gitlab.com/orangepill.nl/ontvangbitcoin.nl" 
class="copyright">Fork @ Gitlab.</a></p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment:  Is that on the site you linked to the `CSS` file? What do you mean by screens bigger than 2050px? Can you post a screenshot of the `overflow`?

Comment: sure I will add it.

Comment: @deEr. thanks for commenting my question. yep it is on the site which I linked to the css. I added a left and right paddings for the screens bigger than 2050px for make visible the background image nicely. But after that I found this trouble. Also I added a screenshot of it.

Comment: Safe to say, that devices that screensize have to be invented yet. Am I right? 

Comment: Try setting a `max-width` minus the `padding` to the navbar.

Comment: @deEr. yes.it is.

Comment: @deEr. Can you explain me a bit how I do max-width minus padding? I am a newbie for this.

Comment: How much `padding-right` did you give? 

Comment: @deEr. Here is the padding left and right for body


    body {
        padding-left: calc((100vw - 1900px) * (15 - 100) / (700 - 1000));
        padding-right: calc((100vw - 1900px) * (15 - 100) / (700 - 1000));
    }

Comment: Is it `max-width:calc(2050px-(100vw - 1900px) * (15 - 100) / (700 - 1000))`? Is that the world-formula you have there?

Comment: @deEr. no. I added the padding right and left for it.

Comment: This formula remembers me of me calculating `vw` of `font-size` with Javascript. Your formula is very advanced. I calculate the `max-width`to be `max-width: 1965px`.

Comment: I took 2050px as 100vw. Calculated it completely out. And took once the result for left, and once again the result for the right `padding` off of it. 